# How to divide a text into parts based on the user's input size

Tags: jquery

If a user enters `2` and the input is `soulkewl` . I need the output to be divide into two equal parts [or based on the user's input] .So the output will be

```
 1. soul 
 2. kewl
```

suppose if size given by user is `2`  like `soulsunny`

```
1.souls
2.unnyz
```

suppose if size given by user is `3`  like `soulsunny`

```
 1.sou
 2.lsu
 3.nny
```

How to achieve this ?

```
Code what i have tried so far is in this link
```

[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/soul/bmv24/2/)

In this link i am splitting the text using `split(" ")` but i am confused how to split or divide into equal parts using jquery

Note if the text is of `odd numbers` it should add one alphabet like `z`

Comment: first what if the word has odd count

Comment: add a alphabet z to it? nice point

Comment: one more thing... is this a word or sentence. you use " " (space) for split but the given word has no space

Comment: can you update your question with an example of the odd number one - ie where to add the z!!!

Comment: @Arif i meant i know to split the word using split

Comment: have a look at substring - you dont really need jQuery ...http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Comment: @ManseUK, Ewwww, w3schools, ewwwww.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
$("#4").click(function() {
    $fulltext =$("#fulltext").val();
    var userSize = $("#userSize").val();
    var sizecount = $fulltext.length;
    while (sizecount % userSize > 0) {
        $fulltext += "z";
        sizecount = $fulltext.length;
    }
    var splitsize = sizecount / userSize;
    for (var i = 0; i < userSize; i++) {
        $("#part" + (i+1) + "text").val($fulltext.substr(i*splitsize,splitsize));
    }
});
```